# Angular ng-repeat how do i add sums

Tags: angularjs

I have a sales table that I want loop and add the total as I go. I have something like this.

```
<h1>Sale</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th> 
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.price}}</td>
    <td>{{item.price +=item.price}}</td>
  </tr>
```

This this what I want

```
<h1>Sale</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th> 
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Burrito</td>
    <td>$2.00</td>
    <td>$2.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Taco</td>
    <td>$1.00</td>
    <td>$3.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Quesadilla</td>
    <td>$4.00</td>
    <td>$7.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How do I add the previous price to the total as my ng-repeat loops thru it.

Comment: Don't do that in the view. Do the totaling in the controller and then simply display this subtotal value in the view.

Comment: I recomend you to do this tutorial it has an example similar to this, I learned a lot and it is very useful as an introduction to Angular: https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js

Comment: I think @MikeVelazco gave you the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a method that evaluates the subtotal:

```
  $scope.getSubTotal = function(index) {
    var subtotal = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < index+1; i++) {
      var item = $scope.items[i];
      subtotal += item.price;
    }
    return subtotal;
  }
```

At your table, pass in the index:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
  <td>{{item.name}}</td>
  <td>{{item.price}}</td>
  <td>{{getSubTotal($index)}}</td>
</tr>
```

Working [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/J7cJyjoiU9mCdjVKVmls?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<td>{{item.price +=items[$index-1].price}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

total needs only once means in that table use like this...

```
<td>Total: {{ getTotal() }}</td>

$scope.getTotal = function(){
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++){
        var item = $scope.items[i];
        total += item.price;
    }
    return total;
}
```